# Merge two data frames in pandas based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have two dataframes: Weather and Guest Counts. To simplify they look like these:

[image]

[image]

I was trying to merge two data frames based on the "date" and "time_period" columns. The ideal result looks like something like this:

[image: !]

I did this but nothing came out. I am not sure what the issue is.

```
f = pd.merge(left=df2,right=dp2, left_on=['date','time_period'], right_on=['date','time_period'])
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Can you post the actual data instead of picture of it

Comment: Can you create a concatenated column of those two, merge on that, then drop the column?

Comment: @Chris  I can't post the actual one since it's confidential

Comment: @Kyle That works. Thanks!